# How to retrieve image from `database`?

Tags: php, ios

I am using local host. I inserted the image in database by `base64encoding` method. But my code to retrieve image is not working.

**Client Side:**

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/lastImage.php"];
NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSURLRequest *req=[[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];

NSData *urldata=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&response error:nil];
NSDictionary *al=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urldata options:0 error:nil];
NSString *name=[al objectForKey:@"name"];
NSString *imgPath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"upload/%@",name];
NSString *escstr=[imgPath stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *imageda=[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:escstr];
_downlimg.image=[[UIImage alloc]initWithData:imageda];
NSLog(@"%@",name);
```

**Is there any problem in giving path. or Should I give this path in the server side**

**Server Side:**

```
<?PHP
$host='localhost';
$name='root';
$pwd='';
$db='i';
$conn=mysql_connect($host,$name,$pwd);
mysql_select_db($db,$conn);
if($conn)
{

$sql=mysql_query("select name from j  order by id desc limit 1");

if($sql)
{

$resultArray=array();
$tempArray=array();

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
$tempArray=$row;
array_push($resultArray,$tempArray);

}
echo json_encode($tempArray);
}
}
?>
```

Comment: So `name` is the link to your image? Also, what does `escstr` return?

Comment: You need to `decode` the base64 encoded image data coming from PHP. [See this](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=base64%20ios)

Comment: `,name ` is a just holding the name of image , not its link. And`escstr` is a string to make a valid path with no space.@Darren

Comment: But it is just a string that is coming from database.@iphonic